# loading a xib view on orientation change in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get my keybordview to switch on orientation change - I have my views within my .xib hooked up with @IBOutlet then I call them with loadInterface() inside of viewDidLoad() I was hoping that my call in viewDidLoad would update the interface but I don't think it's working quite how I thought - it doesn't break anything but it doesn't work either (though, I've made tons of progress from last week.).

I have a feeling it's something with the orientation change...

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

@IBOutlet var keyboardViewPortrait: UIView!
@IBOutlet var keyboardViewLandscape: UIView!

func loadInterface(){
    var keyboardNib = UINib(nibName: "keyboardView", bundle: nil)

    UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()

    if self.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape {
        self.keyboardViewLandscape = keyboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as UIView
        view.addSubview(self.keyboardViewLandscape)
        view.backgroundColor = self.keyboardViewLandscape.backgroundColor
    }
    else if self.interfaceOrientation.isPortrait {
        self.keyboardViewPortrait = keyboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as UIView
        view.addSubview(self.keyboardViewPortrait)
        view.backgroundColor = self.keyboardViewPortrait.backgroundColor
    }

    self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: "advanceToNextInputMode", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)       
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
    loadInterface()

    ...
}
}
```

*update

I think rdelmar set me on the right path but something is still missing.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your assigning the same view to self.keyboardViewLandscape, and self.keyboardViewPortrait (in both cases that's the view you get from keyboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0]). One of those properties should be assigned to the object at index 1. Also, it might be better to use the new method for dealing with rotation, viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:. You also need to remove the previous view when you add the new one.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var keyboardViewPortrait: UIView!
    var keyboardViewLandscape: UIView!
    var keyboardNib = UINib(nibName: "keyboardView", bundle: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.keyboardViewPortrait = keyboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as UIView
        view.addSubview(self.keyboardViewPortrait)
        view.backgroundColor = self.keyboardViewPortrait.backgroundColor
    }

    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){

        if size.width > size.height {
            self.keyboardViewPortrait.removeFromSuperview()
            self.keyboardViewLandscape = keyboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[1] as UIView
            view.addSubview(self.keyboardViewLandscape)
            view.backgroundColor = self.keyboardViewLandscape.backgroundColor
        }
        else {
            self.keyboardViewLandscape.removeFromSuperview()
            self.keyboardViewPortrait = keyboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as UIView
            view.addSubview(self.keyboardViewPortrait)
            view.backgroundColor = self.keyboardViewPortrait.backgroundColor
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to call willTransitionToViewSize() and is there another way to define views in keyboardView than '@IBOveride var keyboardViewLandscape: UIView!' ? I think this should work but I'm still not getting the orientation to switch  at all.

Comment: @glasstongue, you don't have to call willTransitionToViewSize, it's called automatically on rotation. I'm not sure what you mean by your second comment. The code in viewDidLoad always loads the portrait view (the view at index 0) the way I wrote the code.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have to declare 'var keyboardViewPortrait: UIView!' as @IBOutlet in order to call it - I also don't understand if the code in viewDidLoad will work cooperativly with 'viewWillTransitionToSize' or not.
*Deleted previous comments that were unclear

Comment: @glasstongue, I'm not sure what your problem is. I tested this code, and it works fine for me. You don't need any IBOutlets, as you can see in my code, I'm not using them. The method willTransitionToSize:coordinator: is not called when the app first launches which is why I put code in viewDidLoad to load the portrait view. After that, it is called each time you rotate.

Comment: I have a feeling `class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController ` might have some restrictions when dealing with transition states that `class ViewController: UIViewController` would normally use.

Comment: @glasstongue, so what result does your current code give? Does it load the keyboard? Is viewWillTransitionToSize called?

Comment: It brings up the portrait view and on rotate it keeps the portrait view. I just called a NSLog inside of `if size.width > size.height ` and it doesn't get called on rotate.

Comment: @glasstongue, does the else clause get called, or is the function not being called at all?

Comment: Just added a NSLog to the `viewWillTransitionToSize` and the function is not getting called at all.